# Java - StringBuilder not accessible after while loop in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, stringbuilder

```
class myThread extends Thread {

myThread(Socket socket) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(socket);
}

public void run() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            sb.append(sc.next());
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());      

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);      
    }
}
```

This code doesn't output anything. However, If I move the `System.out.println(sb.toString());` into the while loop, it does.
I have no idea why this is, but I need the code to output first AFTER the while loop is complete.

**How would one go about to print the StringBuilder.toString() after the while-loop is complete?**

Comment: I strongly suspect that the problem is that the loop isn't ending, because the socket isn't being closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `socket` is probably never being closed, and the `scanner` is just blocking on `hasNext()`.

Close the `socket` and it should finish.

Comment: Works now. Thank you!